# How to convert PDF to text file in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have to retrieve text from PDF file. But using the following code I only get empty text file.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    pagenumber = i + 1;
    filename = pagenumber.ToString();
    while (filename.Length < digits) filename = "0" + filename;
    filename = "_" + filename;
    filename = splitFile + name + filename;
    // step 1: creation of a document-object
    document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pagenumber));
    // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filename + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));

    // step 3: we open the document
    document.Open();

    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pagenumber);
    int rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(pagenumber);
    if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
    {
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pagenumber).Height);
    }
    else
    {
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
    }
    // step 5: we close the document

    document.Close();
    PDFParser parser = new PDFParser();
    parser.ExtractText(filename + ".pdf", filename + ".txt");
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how should I extract text from PDF?

Comment: The code you use for creating the partial PDFs containing one page of the original each seems to use iTextSharp classes. That PdfParser class on the other hand is not from that library, is it? Where is it from? And why don't you use the PdfTextExtrator in iText? You would not have to split up the document like you do in that case. Please also supply a sample PDF which produces your problems.

Comment: If that PdfParser is from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET, don't be surprised you get no good output --- that PdfParser is very naively implemented.

Answer (score 12):

For text extraction with iTextSharp, take a current version of that library and use

```
PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pageNumber);
```

Beware, there was a bug in the text extraction code in some 5.3.x version which has meanwhile been fixed. Make sure, therefore, that you're using a current 5.5.x version.

Comment: iTextSharp is now called "iText 7 for .NET"or "itext7-dotnet" on github:  [link](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet). It's recommended to add itext7 with Nuget to your solution.

Comment: The answer uses the itext 5.x APIs. Thus, while in general updating to itext 7 is a good idea, it doesn't help in respect to this answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

namespace Pdf2Text
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!args.Any()) return;

            var file = args[0];
            var output = Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".txt");
            if (!File.Exists(file)) return;

            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
            File.WriteAllText(output, ConvertToText(bytes), Encoding.UTF8);
        }

        private static string ConvertToText(byte[] bytes)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                var reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
                var numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                for (var currentPageIndex = 1; currentPageIndex <= numberOfPages; currentPageIndex++)
                {
                    sb.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, currentPageIndex));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//call Create_pdf() function when Done button pressed;

EditText et_Text=findViewById(R.id.EditText);

String projectname="MyPdf";

public  void Create_pdf(){
    Document doc =new Document();
    String outPath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+projectname+".pdf";
    try {
       PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(outPath));
       doc.open();
       doc.add(new Paragraph(et_Text.getText().toString()));
       doc.close();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `EditText et_Text=findViewById(R.id.EditText);` isn't this Java on Android? The tags even include `c#`.