# Reading a part of PDF file in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, partial

I have many large size PDF files that I need to only read a part of them. I want to start reading the PDF file and write it to another file like a txt file, or any other type of files.
However, I want to make a limitation on the size of the file that I am writing in. When the size of txt file is about 15 MB, I should stop reading the PDF document and then I keep the created txt file for my purpose.
Does anyone can help me how can I do this in C#?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Here is the code that I use for reading the whole file; (image content is not important for me)

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"F:\1.pdf"))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"F:\test.txt"))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();                       
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                    sw.Flush(); 
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there a library you are using for reading the PDFs? Does it support stream reading?

Comment: So you're asking how to read a part of a file. Do you already know how to read all the file?

Comment: You definitely will need a Pdf library. Which one do you choose?

Comment: I hate to say this, but Aspose is your friend here. Hate it because it's one of the few libraries available around, and has way too many bugs.

Comment: I have already used iTextSharp library. It works on a windows app but not on web app with Asp.net.

Comment: Well, there are a number of PDF libraries out there, you don't have to use Aspose if you don't want to.

Comment: Which problems did you encounter with iTextSharp in asp.net?

Comment: Trying to read a Pdf with a `StreamReader` almost certainly will result in gibberish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF can't be read directly using .NET. You should first convert PDF to text (or XML, or HTML).

there are lot of PDF libraries capable of converting PDF to text like [iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953965/how-to-convert-pdf-to-text-file-in-itextsharp) (most popular and open-source) and lot of [other tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software)

To control the size of the output text files you should

- get number of pages from PDF
- run pdf to text conversion page by page meanwhile checking the output text file size
- once file size is over 15 MB just stop the conversion and move to another file

Answer (score 1):

You have to use PDF library to do this.There are a lot of free and paid PDF libraries out there which can be used to do your task. Recently I have used [EO.pdf](http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/Pdf/Default.aspx) library to read pdf page and extract page content. The best part is that it has NuGet package and also continuously developed. The cons is **you have to pay for commercial use.**